# What for kotlin console application to execute all async tasks before program exit

Tags: kotlin

I've a command line app what execute some async tasks:

```
class Main {
    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {

            GlobalScope.run {
                launch {
                    FetchMovies().execute(7)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I run the main method with gradle, here the configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'br.com.alessi.parser.main.Main'

// optional:  add one string per argument you want as the default JVM args
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Xms512m", "-Xmx1g"]
```

So I run it: `$ ./gradlew run`

When I run it the program doesn't way for the async executions. How I tell my program to wait until FetchMovie().execute() completes?

I tried with Thread.sleep() but it is of course a bit inaccurate.

--- EDIT

from coroutines documentation I could do this:

```
val job = GlobalScope.run {
                launch {
                    FetchMovies().execute(7)
                }
            }

            job.join()
```

But I cannot call job.join() inside a non-suspended method and if I make main suspended I cannot run with via command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using runBlocking,  as in this example from the coroutines doc.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch { // launch new coroutine in the scope of runBlocking
        delay(1000L)
        println("World!")
    }
    println("Hello,")
}
```

This works as described with the following build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.11'
}
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "MainKt"
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.0'
//    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.5"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: yes, doing that is same as mark main as suspend. gradle doesn't find the main method this way.

Comment: I guess I am not sure what you mean,  I don't see how you mark your main,  or what you mean by gradle not finding the main function ... I added the build.gradle file that I used and it seems to work exactly as documented

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong I wil check it later

Comment: It works. I think I was having some mistake in build file, thanks